# Как закрыть программу после закрытия Messagebox?

Tags: python, tkinter

Как можно осуществить закрытие программы после закрытия Messagebox в tkinter? Закрытие самой программы происходит с помощью библиотеки sys и команды `sys.exit()`. Но вот проблема в том как эту команду связать с закрытием диалогового окна?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import sys

root = tk.Tk()

def mess():
    mess = messagebox.showinfo("Кнопка нажата!!!",'После нажатия ОК программа закроется!!!')

root.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: mess())

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Пробовали добавлять эту команду после вызова Messagebox?

Comment: @insolor, да, к сожалению не работает.

Comment: Добавьте код в вопрос

Comment: @insolor, кажись нашёл ответ на свой вопрос. Сейчас попробую и напишу ответ

Comment: Но код в вопрос добавьте все равно.

Comment: Могу подсказать способ `root.destroy()`. Может так попроще будет. Или принципиально `sys.exit()`?

Comment: @Макс, ниже я уже сам дал ответ. И у `root.destroy()` есть недочёты, т.к. остаются ещё работающие файлы, а мне нужен полный выход из программы, потому использовал `sys.exit()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо было посмотреть что оставляет после закрытия. В моём случае - ok. Таким образом выходит:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import sys

root = tk.Tk()

def mess():
    mess = messagebox.showinfo("Кнопка нажата!!!",'После нажатия ОК программа закроется!!!')
    if mess == 'ok':
        sys.exit()

root.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: mess())

root.mainloop()
```